# What is "gap" in collection?

Tags: c#, collections

I have MeasureUp 70-483 C# practice test. One question is very confusing:

You use Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 to create an application. Your application must store a collection of people in a particular order. If one person is removed from the collection, the collection automatically resizes itself to not leave any gaps. Also, accessing a person from the collection must not remove the person from the collection. You need to choose a collection class.
Which class should you use?

LinkedList | Queue | Stack | ArrayList

According to MeasureUp answer is LinkedList. When item is removed from ArrayList it also resizes itself automatically. I checked it through it's Count property. Why MeasureUp chose LinkedList over ArrayList?

Comment: Nobody uses `ArrayList` any more. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks). Also removing an item means every subsequent item needs to move up the chain which is very slow.

Comment: There is also a confusing explanation according to MeasureUp: "You should not use the ArrayList class. This class implements an ordered array that allows you to access items by index. Removing an item does not automatically resize the collection, so it leaves gaps."

Comment: The issue is when you are using a for loop and removing ant item in the middle. If you have index  3,4,5 and you remove 3.  Then next time through the loop you end up skipping 4 and processing 5.  Deleting the 3rd item now the fifth item becomes the fourth item.  The solution is when removing to enunerate backwards through the loop starting at last item and moving towards the beginning.

Comment: That question is very poorly worded.

Answer (score 1):

`Count` is how many items are in the list, not necessarily how many items are actually allocated.

That being said, I don't believe there's anything stopping `LinkedList` from 'reserving' space for extra (or previously deleted) items.

Comment: LinkedList doesn't reserve space. It keeps track of the head of the list (as a `LinkedListNode<T>`) and provides methods for traversing it (see [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/compmod/system/collections/generic/linkedlist.cs)).

Answer (score 1):

> If one person is removed from the collection, the collection **automatically resizes** itself to not leave any gaps.

My interpretation (in hindsight) is that a `LinkedList` Abstract Data Type automatically resizes on removal of an item, whereas an `ArrayList` is based on manually resizing the underlying array by moving elements around (incurring performance penalty)

Needless to say, the working is internal to the BCL Data Types, and from a framework user's perspective, there is "no gap" and they only differ in performance and some other such characteristics.

I am sure the language could have been better. Interestingly, all the mentioned BCL datatypes fit the question, if you ignore the essence of the question and focus purely on the language used.

Answer (score 1):

An `ArrayList` is an antique collection type (dating from the pre-Generic v1.x timeframe).  It is essentially an array that acts like a list.  If you remove something from the middle, it "leaves" a gap in the array, that, I believe, it fills by moving every element in the array down one cell.  As @DavidG noted, no one uses this type anymore; they use `List<T>` instead.

A `LinkedList` is, well, a linked list.  The first node in the list points to (i.e., is linked to) the next node, the second to the third, and so on.  If you insert a node (*c*) between two other nodes (*a* and *b*), then node *a* is adjusted to point to *c*, and c would be set to point to *b*.  If you were to remove a node (say node *y* from a list like *x*, *y*, *z*), then *x* is adjusted to point to *z*, and *y* effectively disappears (without references to it, it's eligible for garbage collection).

Items in array lists are easily addressable via index (they are arrays under the covers after all).  If you were to access the 100th item in a Linked list, you'd need to start from the first node, following all the pointers to all the other nodes until you got to the 100th one.  If you then asked for the 99th, the traversal of the list would start all over again.